# Which compileSdkVersion should I use in my android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using latest dependencies in my project. My `minSdkVersion` is set as 15 and `targetSdkVersion` is 26. Which build tools and `compileSdkVersion` should I use so that the app can be run even in Adnroid 5.

Here are the details-

```
 compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.shoppingbull"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```

Will these work fine in all devices or I have to reduce the CompileSdkVersion?

Comment: latest one you can use for any android version as if/else condition for that.

Comment: min sdk version is ok. You can keep it at 15 although there wont be much users using this version. But your target sdk version should always be the latest one so that you can use the latest features of Android as introduced by Google.

Comment: API level 21  for Android 5.0, You can set the minSdkVersion 21 (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#5.0) -  Use compileSdkVersion latest - that is 28

Answer (score 1):

Always follow this,

```
minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion
```

Because, when you develop app always target the latest SDK so that you provide the latest features of Google to your user.

Answer (score 0):

According to [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) if you want to make your App can be run in Adnroid 5 and newer, **you should set the minSdkVersion to 21**

> tip: don't make your minSdkVersion lower than 21

Answer (score 0):

Your application will work in the range of `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` api level.

You should target your app to the latest version of Android SDK version (see [SDK Platform release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)) to make sure you've covered all the Android version. It also force you to check if your code is working correctly with the latest version.

So, change your app build.gradle to something like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.shoppingbull"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28  // latest stdk
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` should be the same, and the latest. That's `28` at the current time of writing.

`minSdkVersion` dictates the minimum version your app will support, so having a compile/target of `28` will still let you run on `15`.